# What do I do when my computer won't boot after a drop?

Tags: boot, laptop

I dropped my computer and now when I start it up it says:

> Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected
>   boot device and press a key.

I thought turning it back off, then on would work, but I get the same thing. I have a Toshiba.

What should I do?

Comment: Take it to a computer repair shop and tell them to have a look at it.

Comment: @karel is correct. Drive may be dead or just loose.

Comment: Never seen a hard drive come "loose" in a laptop, they are secured rather well. HD is toast.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't mean to dislike the comment. It's my first time using this web site but by the looks of it I'm going to had to take it to a computer repair shop.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much what @karel says.

Its possible that the hard drive connector has just been dislodged (hopefully), however it is unfortunately likely that the drop has damaged the hard drive in the computer and will need to be replaced.

Depending on your skill (and to a lesser extent the type of computer) it may be possible for you to open it up and reseat the drive.  The exact details on how you do this will depend on the model, but on most computers if you look at the back of them you will find a hard drive symbol (looks like a cylinder) - if you unscrew the screws with that symbol the hard drive will be located underneath, and it may be possible to reseat it.